# How to import a cocoa touch framework with a higher deployment target in an app that supports a lower deployment target?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a cocoa touch framework with iOS deployment target 11.0 that I'm embedding in an app with deployment target iOS 10, and, expectedly, I'm getting

> Module file's minimum deployment target is ios11.0 v11.0

Is it possible to somehow embed this framework into the app, without changing the app's or framework's deployment targets?

I learned that this is possible for OS X frameworks by [weak linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html).

And tried my luck by passing the -weak_framework to linker flags but couldn't make it work.

I'd really appreciate some pointers on how to conditionally compile the Swift code that uses the imported module functionality too.

Comment: What happens if someone is using iOS 10? What do you want to happen? Why would you design this sort of setup? There's a reason the framework's target is iOS 11, correct?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure by saying "own" that this is something I'm developing and I can recompile if I need to. (as opposed to using some 3rd party framework I have no control over). Too much detail @ElTomato?

Comment: @dfd, when someone uses iOS 10 my framework feature will simply be turned off / unavailable. This framework is based on ARKit (the reason why the target is iOS 11). So basically, I'm extending an existing iOS 10 app with AR capability. makes sense?

Comment: Makes much sense - wasn't sure you could get away with that. I take it using a conditional build directive (I think that's the proper term) like `if #available(iOS 11, *)` doesn't work?

Comment: if #available was the first thing I considered, but I'm getting this error exactly where I _import module_ and it can't be used there.

Comment: I had a feeling it wouldn't work. I can't think of any way to wrap the iOS 11 framework into another iOS 10 framework - ??? - and the only other things I can think of are separate app IDs, be it two apps or one (iOS 10) with a free IAP (iOS 11).

Comment: Any luck with resolving this?